# How to break the loop of node.js script for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have code for discord bot written on javascript for node.js. This code makes role to change colors like a rainbow.

```
    async function colorchanger (){
      for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length - 1; i++){
          myRole.setColor(colorArray[i]);
      }
    }

    if (cmd === `start`){
        console.log(`rainbow`);
        stop = 0;

      for (var rain = 0; rain < 999; rain++){
        setTimeout(colorchanger, 1000);
        if (stop === 1) break;
      }
    }
      if (cmd === `stop`){
          console.log(`stoped`);
          stop = 1;        
    }
```

But I have a problem. When I write in discord command "start" all work fine and role start changing colors, and in the console, I have message "rainbow". But when I write in discord command "stop" script don't stop changing colors of role, but in the console, I have a message "stopped". How can I manually stop this loop or reload this script?

UPDATE:
It's doesn't help. I made this code

```
function colorchanger (){
  for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length - 1; i++){
      myRole.setColor(colorArray[i]);
          console.log(`iteration`);

  }
}

if (cmd === `start`){
    console.log(`rainbow`);
    interval = setInterval(colorchanger, 10000);
}
else if (cmd === `stop`) {
        // stop execution of the interval previously created by setInterval
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(`stoped`);
    }
```

for see in console what program do. But after I write stop, I see in console "stopped", but I still have iteration in console appear every 10 seconds and role keep changing colors.

Comment: may be you should change `if (stop === 1) break;` to `if (stop == 1) break;`

Comment: nope, it's don't help

Comment: `setTimeout` is not a blocking statement. Calling it 1000 times will just call the `colorchanger` function 1000 times in 10 second instantly, with no delay between them.

Comment: setTimeout  was used there for the delay, not for blocking https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

Answer (score 0):

You are firing the color change loop all at once. To achieve what you want to do, you should use interval and clear intervals. I put a sample here, I don't know if it is correct in your current implementation (I made interval variable as global, please adapt to your use).

```
    async function colorchanger (){
      // not efficient code, as all will be fired at once every 1000 ms
      for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length - 1; i++){
          myRole.setColor(colorArray[i]);
      }
    }

    if (cmd === `start`) {
        console.log(`rainbow`);
        // repeat colorchanger every 1000ms until clearInterval is called
        interval = setInterval(colorchanger, 1000);
    }
    else if (cmd === `stop`) {
        // stop execution of the interval previously created by setInterval
        clearInterval(interval); 
    }
```

Comment: It's doesn't help. I made this code
function colorchanger (){
  for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length - 1; i++){
      myRole.setColor(colorArray[i]);
          console.log(`iteration`);

  }
}

if (cmd === `start`){
    console.log(`rainbow`);
    interval = setInterval(colorchanger, 10000);
}
else if (cmd === `stop`) {
        // stop execution of the interval previously created by setInterval
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(`stoped`);
    }
for debug in console. But after i write stop, i still have iteration in console apear every 10 seconds